# Resources for European studying for California driver's license?

Tags: usa, eu-citizens, driving-license, california

I'm interested in resources that I can use to study for California driver's license theoretical exam on my own.

However, since I've already have a European one, I'd like to find some resource that puts emphasis on differences between European and US/California regulations.

Comment: A hint for the practical exam: If the examinator wants to be really a pain, he'll expect you stop so that you can still see the line. Mine gave me a downmark for every single stop sign on the course. Fortunately, there were only 13 stop signs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best resource is the [CA Driver's Handbook](http://apps.dmv.ca.gov/pubs/hdbk/driver_handbook_toc.htm) on the DMV site. While most of the rules are generally similar, almost all the areas have subtle differences. Instead of trying to remember your home country rules and the CA differences, it will be much more efficient to just learn the CA rules.

Comment: Can confirm that this is a good way to go.

Comment: Good advice. Did that, passed the test on the very first attempt. I've only read handbook once, then did trial tests on-line.

Answer (score 6):

I asked a pretty similar question as I was surprised we could sometimes turn on red in the US (major offense in France) and wanted to find some good resources that would just give the differences: [What are the differences between French road signs and American road signs?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/23244/1810).

Comments and answers pointed me to three useful resources:

- [What are the main differences in traffic regulations between the US/Europe?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/711/1810)
- [Road signs of the United States](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Road_signs_of_the_United_States)
- [European road signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_European_road_signs)

The DMV manual is indeed the reference, but a diff is very useful too as often the hardest part is to get rid of old habits.

PS: in some states you can [convert your driving license to a state driving license](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/22413/1810).